# Что делает этот код?

Tags: javascript, polymer

Что попадает в переменную "s"? И если не сложно, то по шагам объяснить этот код (Ниже есть пояснения к коду, но они не достаточно ясные для меня).

```
usersAddedOrRemoved: function(changeRecord) {
if (changeRecord) {
  changeRecord.indexSplices.forEach(function(s) {
    s.removed.forEach(function(user) {
      console.log(user.name + ' was removed');
    });
```

Из документации Полимера:

> Use an array mutation observer to call an observer function whenever
>   an array item is added or deleted using Polymer's array mutation
>   methods. Whenever the array is mutated, the observer receives a change
>   record representing the mutation as a set of array splices.
>
> Your observer method should accept a single argument. When your
>   observer method is called, it receives a change record of the
>   mutations that occurred on the array. Each change record provides the
>   following property:
>
> indexSplices. The set of changes that occurred to the array, in terms
>   of array indexes. Each indexSplices record contains the following
>   properties:
>
> index. Position where the splice started. removed. Array of removed
>   items. addedCount. Number of new items inserted at index. object: A
>   reference to the array in question. type: The string literal 'splice'.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> Polymer({
>
>   is: 'x-custom',
>
>   properties: {
>     users: {
>       type: Array,
>       value: function() {
>         return [];
>       }
>     }
>   },
>
>   observers: [
>     'usersAddedOrRemoved(users.splices)'
>   ],
>
>   usersAddedOrRemoved: function(changeRecord) {
>     if (changeRecord) {
>       changeRecord.indexSplices.forEach(function(s) {
>         s.removed.forEach(function(user) {
>           console.log(user.name + ' was removed');
>         });
>         for (var i=0; i<s.addedCount; i++) {
>           var index = s.index + i;
>           var newUser = s.object[index];
>           console.log('User ' + newUser.name + ' added at index ' + index);
>         }
>       }, this);
>     }
>   },
>   ready: function() {
>     this.push('users', {name: "Jack Aubrey"});
>   },
> });
> ```

Comment: А запустить и в консоль вывести не получается?

Comment: [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) первым аргументом в callback передает текущий элемент последовательности